# Reading data from a various terminals using PHP

Tags: php

I would like to know if there's by any chance a way to communicate with a POS device, a cash register and a magnetic card reader with PHP. By communications I mean reading the output of that device.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Those devices often support serial communication.  PHP doesn't have built-in serial terminal support to my knowledge, but [here's a class that facilitates it](http://code.google.com/p/php-serial/).

Beyond this, depending on the platform you are running, reading and writing to a serial port may merely consist of reading and writing the correct byte streams from a character device like `/dev/ttyS0` using `fopen() fread() fwrite()` on the device's file descriptor.